# Did something change in regards to custom profile fields in WP 4.8.2 (mine have disappeared)?

Tags: profiles

I recently upgraded wordpress to 4.8.2 and on the user page of the admin my custom profile fields are gone. The existing data is still there, I can access it via get_user_meta() if it was previously set. Can anybody fill me in on whats wrong or if im missing something? Thanks.

UPDATE:

Here is the function that makes the profile fields (ive edited it for brevity):

```
function my_profile_fields($profile_fields) {

    // Add new fields
    $profile_fields['account_type'] = 'Account Type';
    return $profile_fields;

}
```

It worked fine before. It worked fine for weeks. Nothing new has changed. No new plugins, just new wordpress.

Comment: Had you modified WP Core? Without seeing the code it's not possible to tell, but nothing in core will have done this, especially if you were using the APIs correctly

Comment: can you show the code that add these fields ?